# Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf

Getting this error on newly installed apache. Apache is accessible on localhost but not working on static ip, when we run on static ip it gives error as

Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

What could be the issue? What is possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have accidentally filtered outbound traffic using a Firewall.

**Check your firewall settings**

Comment: Do you foresee any other issue as well? Does httpd respond back on another port than 80?

Comment: @prasoon It actually depends on your web server installation. Did you change the default port(80)? Some webservers use other ports as you may know already (e.g apache jakarta or tomcat uses 8007,8009 if I recall it correctly), why don’t you just disable your firewall temporarily so it will be turned out if it is the firewall settings fault.